# XMLSerializer : Ignoring Elements in List

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

I got a fine working XMLSerializer for a sophisticated List of 3D models with many different elements. Now I want to serialize another List beside of that, that is saving only few Elements of it. 
I just tried to bar some of them out with [XMLIgnore] but this causes problems in the deserialization of my other list.

Here's the Code of my (De)Serializer:

```
public void SerializeObject<T>(T serializableObject, string fileName)
{
    if (serializableObject == null) return;

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(serializableObject.GetType());

    using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, serializableObject);
    }
}

public T DeserializeObject<T>(string fileName)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) return default(T);

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T),overrides);

    using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Maybe its an idea to clone my list, and to remove all the Elements I don't wish to save before Serialization?

Comment: "Maybe its an idea to clone my list, and to remove all the Elements i dont wish to save before Serialization?" Yeap, you should do this, absolutly agree

Comment: you should read up on using `XmlIgnore` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore(v=vs.110).aspx) and maybe edit your question so it includes the code you've written to deal with the attribute, should you still be stuck.

Comment: Make a second class that inherits the first class.  Then override object the you want to ignore and add the XmlIgnore tag to these items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base derived relation to build your collection type where one ignore serialization and other override what you ignored.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual bool BaseMember { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string DerivedMember { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class XmlIgnore : BaseClass
{
    // no XmlIgnore
    public override bool BaseMember
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseMember;
        }
        set
        {
            base.BaseMember = value;
        }
    }
}
```